# Spark Caching: RDD Only 8% cached

Tags: scala, memory-management, apache-spark, distributed-computing, rdd

For my code snippet as below:

```scala
val levelsFile = sc.textFile(levelsFilePath)
val levelsSplitedFile = levelsFile.map(line => line.split(fileDelimiter, -1))
val levelPairRddtemp = levelsSplitedFile
                              .filter(linearr => ( linearr(pogIndex).length!=0))
                              .map(linearr => (linearr(pogIndex).toLong, levelsIndexes.map(x => linearr(x))
                              .filter(value => (!value.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !value.equalsIgnoreCase(" ") && !value.equalsIgnoreCase("null")))))
                              .mapValues(value => value.mkString(","))
                              .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(24))
                              .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)

levelPairRddtemp.count // just to trigger rdd creation
```

**Info**

1. The size of the file is ~ 4G
2. I am using 2 `executors`(5G each) and
   12 cores.
3. `Spark` version: 1.5.2

**Problem**

When I look at the `SparkUI` in `Storage tab`, What I see is :

[image]

Looking inside the `RDD`, seems only 2 out of 24 `partitions` are cached.

[image]

Any explanation to this behavior, and how to fix this.

**EDIT 1**: I just tried with 60 partitions for `HashPartitioner` as:

```
..
.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(60))
..
```

And it **Worked**. Now I am getting entire `RDD` cached. Any guess what might have happened here? Can data skewness cause this behavior?

**Edit-2**: Logs containing `BlockManagerInfo` when I ran again with 24 `partitions`. This time 3/24 `partitions` were cached:

```
16/03/17 14:15:28 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_294_14 in memory on ip-10-1-34-66.ec2.internal:47526 (size: 107.3 MB, free: 2.6 GB) 
16/03/17 14:15:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_294_17 in memory on ip-10-1-34-65.ec2.internal:57300 (size: 107.3 MB, free: 2.6 GB) 
16/03/17 14:15:30 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_294_21 in memory on ip-10-1-34-65.ec2.internal:57300 (size: 107.4 MB, free: 2.5 GB)
```

Comment: might it be possible you took the screenshot before the whole job was finished and it simply didn't get updated? If you have the log files can you look for lines containing `BlockManagerMasterActor`? Otherwise it would mean a bug...

Comment: Mine is a stream job with a cycle life of 5 minutes. I waited for 15 minutes.

Comment: I get a few logs from `BlockManagerMaster`, but only as INFO, no error. Nothing from `BlockManagerMasterActor`

Comment: are they similar to `Added rdd_0_1 in memory on`? How many of them do you have? Of course in the "24" partition case.

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk: Relevant Logs added in Question.

Comment: does that mean you don't see any logs like `Added * in memory on` (where * is usually like `rdd_0_1` etc)? I'm interested if this appears only twice or more times in the logs.

Comment: I get a lot of such log messages, but from `BlockManagerInfo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106619/discussion-between-mohitt-and-mateusz-dymczyk).

Comment: Were you able to understand this behavior? I'm having similar issues with big datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this happens because the memory limits are reached, or even more on point, the memory options you use don't let your job utilize all the resources.

Increasing the #partitions, means decreasing the size of every task, which might explain the behavior.